# How to use Volatile Tables in Python Teradata module PyTD

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

Does anyone know how to use volatile tables in the PyTd Teradata ODBC module? I can run single queries and get the results to return, but if I try to build a query with volatile tables, I keep getting an error. Any help? I'm fairly new to python.

I'm using

```
udaExec = td.UdaExec (appName="dpull", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="ODBC",dsn="tdata", username="un", 
password="pw") as session:

query = """"
create volatile table vol_table
,no fallback, no before journal, no after journal as 
    (
    select a, b, c
    from my_table1
    )
with data primary index (a)
on commit preserve rows

Select vt.a, vt.b, vt.c, t2.a
from vol_table vt
inner join table2 t2
on vt.anything = t2.anything
""""
df = pd.read_sql(query,session)
```

Error:

```
 `InterfaceError: ('SQL_INVALID_HANDLE', 'Invalid handle passed to SQLGetDiagRecW.')`
```

Comment: Don't know about TyPd, but the sql doesn't look right. It should be `PRIMARY INDEX (a) WITH DATA ON  COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; Select...`. `select a,b,c`needs a `from <table>`. Missing `;` at the end. DId you try the sql directly in any Client?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing "from <table>". The sql on the "primary index" works with the logic I have in Teradata. I did adapt this example query from a real query. I'm not having any issues querying through Python Teradata module for a single query, just when I try to add in a volatile table. I'm experimenting with other script to call session.execute(my_query) with each query to see if that works. More to come...

Comment: It is still missing a `;` between query defintion and select, and `; at the end. The `)` after `preserve rows` is too much, there is no correspnding opening `(`.  Depending on the sessions default mode (ansi or Teradata), a `commit;` is needed in ansi-mode after `create table`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but the issue is not with the query. I have typos writing the example query as you've pointed out. Assume the query is good, I want to know why I'm receiving an error trying to use a volatile table in the Teradata Python Module.

Comment: So I tried to run and corrected the query, now I'm receiving the error: `(3932, '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement. ')`

Comment: That error indicates, that you are Teradata mode (aka BTET-mode) and an explicit transaction is not yet closed. There is no open transaction around your statements, hence the DB recieves it as a multistatement. Multistatement = the `;` is not the last character in the line. Both statements are sent to the database as one request to be executed in parallel. Make sure the query-string includes a line-break afte the `;`, or execute them as separate requests within the same session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay thanks to some help on the [Teradata forum](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools/Teradata-Python-Module/m-p/79108/highlight/false#M3713), I was able to solve this. You can add as many queries as you like following the same construct:

```
import teradata as td
import pandas as pd
from teradata import tdodbc

udaExec = td.UdaExec (appName="dpull", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="ODBC",dsn="tdata", username="un", 
password="pw") as session:

query1 = """
    create volatile table vol_table
    ,no fallback, no before journal, no after journal as 
        (
        select a, b, c
        from my_table1
        )
     with data primary index (a)
     on commit preserve rows;
"""
query2 = """
    Select vt.a, vt.b, vt.c, t2.x
    from vol_table vt
    inner join table2 t2
    on vt.a = t2.a
"""
session.execute(query1)
df = pd.read_sql(query2,session)
```